# How can I measure the real total time that an audio file is played (including rewinding and forwarding)

Tags: android, seekbar

for example, the audio file is about 3 minutes..however..while listening the user is moving the seekbar several times....I need the exact time that the user is listening to the audio file to store it in my data base. How can I do it? Thx a lot!

```
     @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (player != null && fromUser) {
                player.seekTo(progress);
                timeView.setText(stringForTime(progress));

                int timeLeft = player.getDuration()-player.getCurrentPosition();



            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: just start a timer when the File is started at first time?

Comment: and how can I measure the interruptions? I mean, if the user is forwarding from minute 1 to minute 2...then the run time to store should be two minutes (e.g. when the duration of audio file is 3minutes)

Comment: Mean what you want to measure?

Comment: the exact time which the user is listening to the audio file

Comment: Player.getCurrentPosition returns the current position, which the user is listening.

Comment: yes and i need an algortihm, which returns the total time that the user is listenting the audio file

Comment: Mean, the total time, the user listened all the song?

Comment: yes not the total time of the song, but the time the user has listened exactly with forwarding and rewinding.

Comment: bofredo given you solution for this.

Comment: ok thx i will to google for timer then

Comment: i cant make it :( could u please send me a link where it is described comprehensively ?